# How to create an annotation with an interface that has a generic?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am trying to create an annotation that will allow me to wrap a (spring) bean with an instance of the supplied class. The interface has a type parameter which is (should not, if possible) not specified by the wrapping class. See the code below for an example of what I mean.

I managed to get a (compilation, haven't tried runtime yet) fix by making `MyWrapperImpl` implement the type parameter with super class of the class used by `MyWrappedClass`, however I would rather not specify it.

How can I keep the type parameter? In other words how can I keep `MyWrapperImpl` as generic as possible?

Annotation:

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.Runtime)
public @interface Wrap {
    Class<? extends MyInterface<?>> classToWrapWith();
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
    T getSomething();
}
```

A wrapper class:

```
public class MyWrapperImpl<T> implements MyInterface<T> {
    private MyInterface<T> wrapped;

    public T getSometing() {
        // Do something special, such as:
        System.out.println("Calling get something from wrapped object");

        return wrapped.getSomething(); // MyWrapperImpl should "use" the type from the wrapped instance.
    }
}
```

Annotated class:

```
// Attempt 1
@Wrap(classToWrapWith = MyWrapperImpl.class) // <-- Compile error "found class<MyWrapperImpl>, required class<? extends MyInterface<?>>"
// Attempt 2
@Wrap(classToWrapWith = MyWrapperImpl<T>.class) // <-- Compile error, cannot select from parameterized type.
public class MyWrappedClass implements MyInterface<SubObject> {
    public SubObject getSomething() {
        return new SubObject();
    }
}
```

Wrapper class with a working fix (Where `SuperObject` is a parent class of `SubObject`, which is used in `MyWrappedClass` (see above)):

```
public class MyWrapperImpl<SuperObject> implements MyInterface<T> {
    private MyInterface<SuperObject> wrapped;

    public SuperObject getSometing() {
        return wrapped.getSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please clarify.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I changed the code to have more descriptive names. Hopefully this helps? If not do you have a concrete suggestion what I can improve?